# Swift - How to set the value of an XCUIElement

Tags: xcode, swift, automated-tests

While trying to implement the new UI Testing in Swift, I tried to set the value of a text field by doing this:

`app.textFields["field_name"].setValue(value, forKey: "any key")`

However, I got an error saying that the key is not found.

So my question is:

a) Is there an easier way to do this?

an if not

b) How do I obtain the correct key so I can set the value of the text field?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are UI testing, you don't usually just set values on objects, you are trying to replicate what the user is doing. In this case you probably want:

```
app.textFields["field_name"].typeText(value);
```

Comment: What if I want to clear whatever is typed in there already  and replace it with something?

Comment: @SalmonKiller The same way the user would clear it - either by pressing backspace multiple types or by clicking the "clear" button.

Comment: @SalmonKiller You can use typeText("\u{8}") to type a backspace character.